# .htaccess rewrite to custom page only for folders that do not exist

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, directory

Every now and then a script will try to load pages on my site from folders that do not exist and I end up with thousands of 404 error logs that I would rather not have to sift through. I cannot figure out how to write a rewrite condition that says: "if the file is in a folder that does not exist..."

Here are two examples that I need to trap:
/weblogs/ (just a folder)
/admin/categories.php/login.php?cpath=&action=new_product_preview (a file in a folder that does not exist)

the rewrite rule will point to something like: /404noted.htm

Thank you!

Daniele

Answer (score 0):

SOmething along the lines of

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404noted.htm/$1
```

It'll check to make sure no file or folder by that name exists and if neither exist, it will then forward to your 404noted.htm file.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, except the rewrite rule was causing a 500 error. I changed it to this: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404noted.htm [NC,L]

Comment: Not long after posting my previous posting, I noticed that the code above essentially replaces my 404 page in all cases. I still want my 404 page to show up for files that do not exist in folders that do exist.